# Problem with making dynamic form based on table field in Vue Js

Tags: laravel, database, vue.js, inertiajs

I got the problem in making program for my company, the concept is you can input mark (nilai) for every sector based on kriteria of the mark you had to fill and it has 5 kriteria. the problem is I have to separate the kriteria based on the kriteria name and when I try the array cant be shown

```
<template>
<div class="space-x-4 sm:-my-px sm:ml-1 sm:flex">
    <jet-button @click="getKriteria1">P1</jet-button>
    <jet-button @click="getKriteria2">P2</jet-button>
    <jet-button @click="getKriteria3">P3</jet-button>
    <jet-button @click="getKriteria4">P4</jet-button>
    <jet-button @click="getKriteria5">P5</jet-button>
</div>

<div class="mt-4">
    <div class="space-x-4 sm:-my-px sm:ml-1 sm:flex" v-if="session === 1" :v-for="(kriteria, index) in kriteria1.data" :key="kriteria.id">
        <label>{{kriteria.sub_kriteria}} : </label>
        <jet-input type="number" class="mt-1 block w-3/4" placeholder="Nilai"
            ref="nilai"
            v-model="form.nilai[index]"
            @keyup.enter="create" />
        <jet-input-error :message="form.errors.nilai" class="mt-2" />                        
    
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

can you guys help me why the kriterias i get cant be show, in the console i can see the kriteria is read and has field but when i try to call it with props it cant be shown and cant be convert to kriteria1

```
<script>

props: {
    penilaians: Array,
    kriterias:Array,

},

data() {
    return {
        session:1,
        kriteria1:[],
        kriteria2:[],
        kriteria3:[],
        kriteria4:[],
        kriteria5:[],            
        form:this.$inertia.form({
            nilai:[],
            foto:[],
            status:[],
            rekomendasi:[]
        }),
    }
},
methods:{

    getKriteria1(){
        this.session = 1;
        this.kriteria1 = kriterias;
        for(let index=0;index<=kriterias.length;index++){
            if(kriterias[index].nama === 'P1'){
                this.kriteria1[index].id = kriterias[index].id;
                this.kriteria1[index].nama = kriterias[index].nama;
                this.kriteria1[index].sub_kriteria = kriterias[index].sub_kriteria;
            }
        }
        

    },
}
</script>
```

i erase the component and import in purpose because it will not affect the question i think

Comment: Can you please a bit of formatting and explain the question a bit better please?

Comment: i already get the answer myself hehe

Comment: Feel free to post it below.

Answer (score -1):

the main idea is to filter the 'kriteria' field to spesific values so i made the filter with getKriteria 1 so i can get 'nilai' form for the 'kriteria'

```
method:{
            getKriteria1(){
            this.session = 1;
            var kriteria = this.kriterias;
            var j=0;
            for(var i=0;i<= kriteria.length;i++){
                if(kriteria[i].nama == 'P1'){
                    this.kriteria1[j] = kriteria[i];

                    j++;
                    
                }
            }
      

        },
}
```

this is the jetstream template of the program :

```
<div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div class="space-x-4 sm:-my-px sm:ml-1 sm:flex"  :v-on:show ="getPenilaianId()">
                <jet-button v-on:click.prevent="getKriteria1()" >P1</jet-button>
                <jet-button v-on:click.prevent="getKriteria2()" >P2</jet-button>
                <jet-button v-on:click.prevent="getKriteria3()" >P3</jet-button>
                <jet-button v-on:click.prevent="getKriteria4()" >P4</jet-button>
                <jet-button v-on:click.prevent="getKriteria5()" >P5</jet-button>
            </div>

            <div class="mt-4">
                <div v-if="session === 1">
                    <div v-for="item in kriteria1" :key="item.id" :v-on:show="getKriteriaId(item.id-1)">
                        <div v-if="item === null"> Tidak ada Kriteria </div>
                        <label>{{item.nama}} - {{item.sub_kriteria}}</label>
                        <jet-input type="number" class="mt-1 block w-3/4" placeholder="Nilai"
                            ref="nilai"
                            v-model="form.nilai[item.id-1]"
                            @keyup.enter="create" />

                        <jet-input-error :message="form.errors.nilai" class="mt-2" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
```